# java.lang.StackOverflowError when joining RDDs - only on a cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I ran into an issue that only happens when I run my spark job on a cluster.
It does not happen when I run in local mode.

Advice on how to fix this issue is more than welcome, but also advice on how to approach/debug this issue will be much appreciated.

The issue I have is when I try to join to rdds, I get a java.lang.StackOverflowError, apparently during object serialization.
Here's some of the stacktrace (it is very long but repeats itself) -

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
```

The issue only happens when I try to join two rdds.

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).count
```

If instead, I'd do

```
rdd1.count
rdd2.count
```

this error will not reproduce.
(To me, it means the issue is somehow related to the fact I join the two RDDs, and not to how the RDDs are constructed, as they seem to be successfully processed individually, but I could be wrong.)

The RDDs are comprised of tuples of simple case classes

```
val rdd1: RDD[(Device, Option[Usage])] = ...
val rdd2: RDD[(Device, Seq(Problem)] = ...
```

Where the case classes have only simple attributes (String, Int, DateTime, Option[?])

```
case class Device(customerId: String, appId: String, deviceId: String, lastEngagement: Option[DateTime], firstSeen: Option[DateTime], lastEngagementUserClass: Option[String])
case class Usage(customerId: String, appId: String, deviceId: String, eventTimestamp: DateTime, appVersion: String, appVersionCode: Int, appSignature: Int, osVersion: String, lifecyclePhase: String, userClass: String)
case class Problem(customerId: String, appId: String, deviceId: String, eventTimestamp: DateTime, problemType: Int, problemSubType: Int, problemReasonId: String)
```

I'm using Spark 1.6.1 and scala 2.10.5.

Any advice?

**UPDATE:**

I realize this is a broad question.
Unfortunately, it is not an easy one to reproduce, because it must run on a spark cluster (does not reproduce in local mode), and also, it does not seem to reproduce with small sample data - at least, I have not been able to create such sample data.

I'm hoping someone who had similar issues would be able to help me. I guess my question is - did you have similar issues? How did you end up solving it? How did you approach the issue to troubleshoot?

Comment: Could you post some sample data that is easy to copy paste so that we can recreate your error? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I agree with @KatyaHandler . This is too broad to answer !

Answer (score 0):

Just following up after I found a solution - writing this here in case someone else has the same issue.

I concluded that the serialization issue was with

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).
```

I concluded that, because the issue did not reproduce when I called

```
rdd1.count()
rdd2.count()
```

effectively forcing each rdd to compute separately.

This assumption is wrong - invoking count does not need to serialize objects at all. It just needs to count each partition and then sum the result.

When I called

```
rdd1.collect()
```

the issue did reproduce, and I was able to dig deeper, and eventually locate the problem that was in my code.